# Coefficients in a Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Suppose that for constant $A_n (n=1,2,3,...)$, we have
\begin{equation}
A_1\,\sin(\frac{\pi\,x}{L})+
A_2\,\sin(\frac{2\,\pi\,x}{L})+
A_3\,\sin(\frac{3\,\pi\,x}{L})+
...+
A_n\,\sin(\frac{n\,\pi\,x}{L})+
...
=0
\end{equation}
for $x\in (0,L)$. Could we conclude that $A_n=0$, $n=1,2,3,...$? I've tried to multiply both sides by $\sin(\frac{n\,\pi\,x}{L})$ and then integrate from $0$ to $L$, and found $a_n=0$. Is this enough to conclude the desired result?

Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: What do you get if multiplying by $sin(\frac{k\pi x}{L})$ for any $k \in 1,2,...,n$?

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of [Uniqueness of Representation by Trigonometric Series](http://math.depaul.edu/mash/monthly_uniqueness.pdf) which states that if
$$\frac{1}{2} a_0 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(a_n \cos nx  + b_n \sin nx\right)$$
converges everywhere to $0$, then all its coefficients are zero. This is a non trivial theorem. See for example the book of Sygmund - Trigonometric series, page 326.

The issue of "your proof" in the original question is that you can't permute the $\sum$ and $\int$ without proper assumptions on the series $A_1\,\sin(\frac{\pi\,x}{L})+
A_2\,\sin(\frac{2\,\pi\,x}{L})+
A_3\,\sin(\frac{3\,\pi\,x}{L})+
...+
A_n\,\sin(\frac{n\,\pi\,x}{L})+
...$.